# Is this question migratable to MO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, math-stackexchange

Is it worth migrating this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1556455/2987) to MO, from math.SE?

It seems elementary but did not get any response on MSE even after 10 days.

Comment: Did you try to get more exposure by placing a bounty?

Comment: @ThomasRot : There are currently 61 featured question on MSE, and me putting a bounty may not be of much help as there isn't even a cursory acknowledgment of the question there. I am already a low Rep user!

Comment: @ThomasRot : Anyway I have started the bounty. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My instinctual feeling is that it would not survive trial by MO if it were migrated. But maybe someone reading the meta post here will go to MSE to help out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the question would be good at MO.
I would vote to close it as off-topic, and believe so would many others.
I see no particular research angle to the question, and I would not consider it otherwise interesting to research mathematicians, either.

That said, I gave you something of an answer at MSE.
I don't know if my way qualifies as a nice way of writing your distribution, but I don't see how one could do much better.
If you (or anyone else, for that matter) want to discuss mathematical details, let us do so where the question is.